# Python add small matrix inside big one

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, multidimensional-array, character

or matrices, and I want to fit the "map" 2d array inside of "cmap", which is +2 bigger, in fact I want to use "cmap" as a frame of "map", but I wanted to do without using one single array (also because I want to randomly generate the characters inside of the "map" 2d array... Did you have any suggestions?

```
rows, cols = (9, 9)
crows, ccols = (rows + 2, cols + 2)
print(crows, ccols)
cmap = [["#" for x in range(crows)] for y in range(ccols)]
map = [["#" for x in range(rows)] for y in range(cols)]
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you’re trying to do? I had trouble following your explanation; how does what you’ve shown fail to provide what you said? [ask]

Comment: Look at this pic https://imgur.com/a/f0iP8tj , i'm trying to insert the red 2d array inside the green one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters and maps - looks like you may be making a game!

Try:

```
border = 1
for i in range(border,len(cmap)-border):
  cmap[i][border:-border] = map[i-border]
```

Comment: THANKS A MILLION! And yeah you're right, it's for a game engine that i'm prototyping in python

Comment: You're welcome!  Also, I forgot to mention that 'map' means something in Python, so you might want to pick a different name for it.  It's unfortunate, because it's such an apt name!  https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Yeah I know I know, also pyCharm give me a warning